# Razor compilation considerably slower in .NET 4.6/Roslyn than 4.5

Tags: c#, razor, roslyn, .net-4.6

I'm compiling some Razor view with the below (pseudo) code:

```
var host = new RazorEngineHost(new CSharpRazorCodeLanguage());
var engine = new RazorTemplateEngine(host);
var razorResult = engine.GenerateCode(reader, viewTypeName, "", null);
var compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters(assemblies.ToArray(), outputAssemblyName);
compilerParameters.TempFiles.KeepFiles = false;
var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var compilationResults = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(compilerParameters, razorResult.GeneratedCode);
```

In .NET 4.5 this took 10s of ms for a reasonably complex view. Since upgrading to .NET 4.6, this now takes seconds :(

I'm referencing `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`

What's changed? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Maybe it's somehow related to this issue? https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3516 If so it's getting fixed.

Comment: Everything changed.  Not an uncommon complaint btw, anti-malware treats Roslyn rather poorly.  So disable it and try again.

Comment: @HansPassant what folders does it write to? `windows/temp` and `Framework64/temp`?

Comment: Not a folder, it uses a named pipe for inter-process communication.  Gets the crappy kind of anti-malware upset, it checks the pipe data for signatures and that bogs down compilation badly.  If this is Avast or AVG or ESET then uninstall asap.

Comment: @AndrewBullock if you use roslyn directly (create a new `CSharpCompilation` with `razorResult.GeneratedCode`) it gets much faster. Don't know if you looked into `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`, but it is an .exe, that's executed from your bin folder....